# Modifying Contact Form Script to Insert Senders Email in Reply to Field

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am using a simple contact form and script on a website. The only issue I have is that I would like the email of the person filling out the form used as the reply to e-mail address rather than my servers address when I receive their submission. This is so I can simply reply to the contact rather than having to copy and paste their address and start a new reply to e-mail.

Any simple way to do this?

The below is the simple code I am using.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/contact.html'); 

$name = $_REQUEST['Person'];  
$company = $_REQUEST['company'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
$state = $_REQUEST['state'];
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$details = $_REQUEST ['details'];
$byphone = $_REQUEST ['Phonebox'];
$emailbox = $_REQUEST['Emailbox'];
$message = "From  $name\n Company $company\n Address $address\n $city $state $zip\n Email  $email\n Phone $phone\n Subject $subject\n\n Details $details\n\n Contact by $byphone $emailbox";

mail ("XXXXXXXXX.com", "Customer Inquiry", "$message", "$email");
?>
```

Comment: It's too simple, I'm afraid. But that's how the perfect code should look like.

Comment: Seriously, you just forgot to post the code (or posted it outside of `code` zone). ) But in fact your question is quite straight-forward - it'll just save SO time to add some functionality to the existing codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

(Example below)

```
<?php
$to      = 'server_owner@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: i_filled_the_form@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: i_filled_the_form@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```